# Iterate through object with props of multiple values leads to Typescript error: Type is not assignable to type never

Tags: javascript, typescript

From version 3.8.+ Typescript have changed resulted type of multiple properties with different types to union and now it calculates as `never`.
If you will iterate through properties of an object and try to do some similar operation to them you will get `Type {some_type} is not assignable to type never` error

Simple example

```
interface Multitypes {
    name: string;
    age: number;
}

type MultitypesKey = keyof Multitypes;

const updateValues = (item: Multitypes, item2: Multitypes, keys: MultitypesKey[] = []) => {

    for (let i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {

        item[keys[i]] = item2[keys[i]]; // this line will show an error

    }

};
```

[playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ts=3.8.3&ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=16&pc=3#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLIFcA2ZhgJ4AOEAzsgN4CwAUMsiHALYQBcyxYUoA5gNzW1wuLOugYAjaHyoBfatXxE0WHApIBpCHmQBeZAGtNAexhLsuQiSnUEhkO2QJMEOFABqcTOhI7kAClwQDKwYZqrEADTIAQwATMHK5kQR%20prE8aEWxBp4ANoAuj75AJQ6AHzkcjTIMIZQfk5gUT4ADDxNADwpeMQAdE4gXGAAFm3AANRjJZRU-LRRkAw5Bt05wHkFutExS6mr61ZVsjMyPEA)

Any suggestion on how to avoid that error and refactor the code above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a generic parameter for the key here:

```
const clearValues = <K extends MultitypesKey>(
  item: Multitypes,
  item2: Multitypes,
  keys: K[] = []
) => {
  for (let i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
    item[keys[i]] = item2[keys[i]];
  }
};
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ts=3.8.3&ssl=8&ssc=1&pln=16&pc=3#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLIFcA2ZhgJ4AOEAzsgN4CwAUMsiHALYQBcyxYUoA5gNzW1wuLOugYAjaHyoBfatXxE0WHApIBpCHmQBeZAGtNAexhLsuQiSnUEhkO2QJMEOFABqcTOhI7kAHjXIEAAekCAAJqQYZqrEGngAfAAU-Mi4EAysUSoWxAA0KWkMAEyZyuZEeSkGeMSsagDaALo+TdQAlDrx5CkwhlDIiU5gqT4ADDwjvvqaxAB0TiBcYAAWE8AA1OsdlDS0qZAM9dXE9cCNzbqFRUczp+dStLIyPEA)

---

The issue is that Typescript needs to be able to infer a more specific type that just `MultitypesKey[]`. But in your original code, `keys` is `MultitypesKey[]` and each time you use it typescript doesn't know its the same array. It needs to know specifically that individual indexes have concrete type.

By making the parameter generic, Typescript knows that `keys` is of `type K[]` and `K` is inferred from whatever is passed in. So now it knows for sure each time you use the same index on `keys` you will get the same type back.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a jsfiddle example with your original code. You can run it to see the first error encountered: https://jsfiddle.net/a9gd23jy/

The error is thrown for the line:

```js
type MultitypesKey = keyof Multitypes;
```

This line throws the error `Uncaught ReferenceError: Multitypes is not defined`.

From the [Typescript documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#index-types):

> For any type T, keyof T is the union of known, public property names of T

The way you're using it is as a way to get a type representing all its property keys as  a union of string literal type. This doesn't seem to work, but I've seen tutorials which use that so maybe it worked this way previously but in newer versions it doesn't.

Regardless, here is a working example with a small change to make it work as *I think* you expected: https://jsfiddle.net/a9gd23jy/3/

Get rid of `type MultitypesKey = keyof Multitypes;`as it's not needed and seems to cause an error. Then just a make small change to the `updateValues` function to use `keyof`:

```js
function updateValues<Key extends keyof Multitypes>(item: Multitypes, item2: Multitypes, keys: Key[] = []) {
    for (let i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
        item[keys[i]] = item2[keys[i]]; 
    }
};
```

Comment: `type MultitypesKey = keyof Multitypes;` is a valid code in the latest 3.9.2 actually, see almost the same answer above